# How do I implement a route in camel to receive messages from a JMS queue?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, weblogic, spring-jms

I've referred to the JMS page of the Camel documentation and many related SO questions [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774424/sending-message-to-weblogic-jms-queue-from-a-camel-route), but I'm unable to find a comprehensive list on the implementation.

I'm using Spring XML along with Camel and Weblogic for the server. I've made a test queue with the following names:

Server: TestJMSServer, Module: TestJMSModule, Queue: TestJMSQueue, CF: TestConnectionFactory.

According to the Camel documentation, my route should look something like this:

```
<camel:route id="test">
        <camel:from uri="jms:TestJMSQueue" />
        <camel:to uri="file:/Users/...." />
</camel:route>
```

This gives me an error saying "connectionFactory must be specified". So exactly what else do I need to add to my applicationContext.xml in order to listen to this queue?

Comment: Have you set up any beans that would reference the location or connection information for you queue? The connection factory Spring is referring to not finding is the JMS Connection Factory that tells the Camel JMS component how to talk to your queue. Can you provide you entire context xml, or at least any parts that would reference camel or spring beans for your JMS queue?

Comment: Please add your jms bean definition in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Camel's jms-component which JMS connection factory to use. Most likely you'll get that from jndi if you're using WebLogic.

In the example below i am looking up the connection factory using spring's `jee:jndi-lookup` (i believe that might even be a name you can use in WebLogic). The looked up factory is then made available as a spring bean with id `myConnectionFactory`.

This connection factory bean is then used for the `connectionFactory` property for camel's `JmsComponent`. Notice the `id` attribute: `jms`. This defines the camel endpoint uri scheme to be used in your routes.

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">


    <jee:jndi-lookup id="myConnectionFactory" jndi-name="jms/connectionFactory"/>

    <route id="test" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <from uri="jms:TestJMSQueue"/>
        <to uri="file:/Users/...."/>
    </route>


    <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory"/>
        <!-- more configuration required based on your requirements -->
    </bean>

    <!--
    example uses  invm amq broker:

    <bean id="anothercnf" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://mybroker"/>
    </bean>
    -->
</beans>
```

*Important Note*: You will need to tune this further (setup transactions, setup concurrent consumers, possible configure a spring jms connection pool)